# In Acrobat 11 where is the PDF settings panel for PDF Optimizer?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, compression

Acrobat 11 is much different than Acrobat 9 but I was wondering where is the panel for PDF compression settings.  In Acrobat 9 you could go to `Advanced -> PDF Optimizer`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Acrobat 11 it would appear the Advanced Options panel is removed.  To access the PDF Optimizer go to `File -> Save As Other... -> Optimzed PDF..`:

[image]

Documentation for Adobe: [Save using PDF Optimizer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7c87.w.html)